# Calling destroy on collection

Tags: backbone.js

I am doing a sample application similar to the Backbone-Todo. But when I am invoking destroy on collection it's giving error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined

How can I solve this problem. Please suggest.

Following is my method code:

```
$(function(){

var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({

defaults: function() {
  return {
    title: "empty todo...",
    order: Todos.nextOrder(),
    done: false
  };
}

});


var TodoList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model : Todo,

  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("todos-backbone"),

  done: function() {
    return this.where({done: true});
  },

  remaining: function() {
    return this.without.apply(this, this.done());
  },

  nextOrder: function() {
    if (!this.length) return 1;
    return this.last().get('order') + 1;
  },

  comparator: 'order'   
});

var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

  tagName:  "li",

  template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

  events: {
    "click a.destroy" : "clear"
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  },

  clear: function(){
    this.model.destroy();
  }
});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: $("#todoapp"),

  statsTemplate: _.template($('#stats-template').html()),

  events: {
    "keypress #new-todo":  "createOnEnter",
    "click #remove-all": "clearCompleted"
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.input = this.$("#new-todo");
    this.main = $('#main');
    this.footer = this.$('footer');

    this.listenTo(Todos, 'add', this.addOne);
    this.listenTo(Todos, 'all', this.render);

    Todos.fetch();
  },

  render: function() {
    var done = Todos.done().length;
    var remaining = Todos.remaining().length;

    if (Todos.length) {
      this.main.show();
      this.footer.show();
      this.footer.html(this.statsTemplate({done: done, remaining: remaining}));
    } else {
      this.main.hide();
      this.footer.hide();
    }
  },

  createOnEnter: function(e){
    if(e.keyCode != 13) return;
    if (!this.input.val()) return;
    Todos.create({
      title: this.input.val()
    })  
    this.input.val('');         
  },

  addOne: function(todo){
    var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
    this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
  },

  clearCompleted: function(){
    _.invoke(Todos, 'destroy');
    return false;
  }
```

});

Comment: Your question may require more context. The original code invokes the method on "Todos.done()", which defers the invocation for when the target object is available (in a good case).

Comment: Hello Eric,
I have provided my app code. Could you figure it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this answer I assume `Todos` is an instance of `TodoList`. I also assume that your error is fired by this function in your `AppView`

```
clearCompleted: function(){
  _.invoke(Todos, 'destroy');
  return false;
}
```

In there you're trying to treat your Backbone.js `Collection` instance like what it is, a collection eg a list. But Backbone collections are not simply lists, they are objects that have the property `models` which is a list that contains all your models. So trying to use underscore's `invoke` [(which works on **lists**)](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke) on an object is bound to cause errors.

But don't worry, Backbone neatly implements many Underscore methods for its `Model` and `Collection`, [including `invoke`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods). This means you can invoke destroy for each model in a collection like this

```
SomeCollection.invoke('destroy');
```

Hope this helps!